# How to get AD user's "Display name" instead of logon name (domain\userid) while exporting "send as" and "full" permissions?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, powershell, scripting, exchange-2013

I have googled and created two scripts . (1), (2)

(1)First one is to export "Full Access" of a shared email box called "ap.cz"

```
Get-Mailbox ap.cz | Get-MailboxPermission | where {$_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} | Select Identity,User,@{Name='Access Rights';Expression={[string]::join(', ', $_.AccessRights)}} | Export-Csv \\myserver\c$\fulla.csv –NoTypeInformation
```

(2)Second one is to export "Send As" of a shared email box called "ap.cz"

```
Get-Mailbox ap.cz | Get-ADPermission | where { ($_.ExtendedRights -like “*Send-As*”) -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not ($_.User -like “NT AUTHORITY\SELF”) } | Select Identity, User, Deny | Export-CSV \\myserver\c$\sendass.csv
```

Both scripts are working fine.

**Output for (1) is similar to this**

[image]

**output for (2) is similar to this**

[image]

But for both occasions I get "`User logon name`" in the format (`domain\userid`) where userid is a number in my organization.

But I need to get `display name/full name` instead of "`User logon name`" while exporting to csv..

I'm not an exchange admin or well versed in exchange/powershell, but i am checking/supporting overall IT infrastructure, and when a manager is asking for a list of names, for "send as" or "full access" for a certain mailbox, I have to export it using above scripts and re-convert `"user logon name"` to `display name` manually.

Can someone please advice how to change both scripts to display `"full name/display name"` instead of `login name` ? I have tried googlin, yet no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$users.user.rawidentity** will eliminate type casting and few more lines...

**"Full Access"** list

```
$users=Get-Mailbox ap.cz | Get-MailboxPermission | where {$_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} 
$ss=$users.user.rawidentity | Where-Object {$_ -notlike "s-1*"}

foreach ($item in $ss){ 
$b = $item.Split("\")
$c=$b.Split("}")[1]
Get-ADUser -identity $c -properties DisplayName | select DisplayName
}
```

**"Send As"** list

```
$users=Get-Mailbox ap.cz | Get-ADPermission | where { ($_.ExtendedRights -like “*Send-As*”) -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not ($_.User -like “NT AUTHORITY\SELF”) } | Select User
$ss=$users.user.rawidentity | Where-Object {$_ -notlike "s-1*"}

foreach ($item in $ss){ 
$b = $item.Split("\")
$c=$b.Split("}")[1]
Get-ADUser -identity $c -properties DisplayName | select DisplayName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got help with my programming friend (Who knows nothing about AD objects) and ended up with below solution..  This might not be the ideal solution, but  Both are working saves the purpose!! Wish to share the solution, so someone can be benefitted and or can suggest a better solution..

**(1)First one is to export "Full Access" of a shared email box called "ap.cz"**

```
 $users=Get-Mailbox ap.cz | Get-MailboxPermission | where {$_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} | Select User

            $num=$users.length

            for

($i=0; $i -lt $num; $i++)
        {
        Try
        {

            $item=$users[$i]
            $itemcast=[string]$item
            $b = $itemcast.Split("\")[1]
            $c=$b.Split("}")[0]

        Get-ADUser -identity $c -properties DisplayName | select DisplayName
        }


        catch
        {
        $error="error"
        }
        }
```

**(2)Second one is to export "Send As" of a shared email box called "ap.cz"**

```
 $users=Get-Mailbox ap.cz | Get-ADPermission | where { ($_.ExtendedRights -like “*Send-As*”) -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not ($_.User -like “NT AUTHORITY\SELF”) } | Select User
    $num=$users.length

    for($i=0; $i -lt $num; $i++)
    {
    Try
    {

        $item=$users[$i]
        $itemcast=[string]$item
        $b = $itemcast.Split("\")[1]
        $c=$b.Split("}")[0]

    Get-ADUser -identity $c -properties DisplayName | select DisplayName
    }


    catch
    {
    $error="error"
    }
    }
```

both scripts were saved as script1.ps1 and script2.ps1  and output was saved to  out-file c:\araa.csv

**How to export to csv**

```
 script2.ps1 | out-file c:\araa.csv
```

Answer (score -2):

Powershell one more way,

```
$gadu=get-aduser username -properties *

$gadu.Displayname
```

Save the output to a var, then adding the name of the filed that we want to look at to the end of the var, think of the $gadu var as table, not as fancy as the formatting as above but is still handy. The get-aduser can be funny about what fields it outputs, so I use the `-properties *` 99% of the time.